# Svelte + Houdini doesn't send cookies client side rendering

Tags: cookies, sveltekit

I'm using Houdini for GraphQL operations. For this setup, my SvelteKit is running from `localhost:5000` and My GQL server is running from `localhost:4000` expecting a cookie sent to it for authentication, and I have set up the `HoudiniClient` like so:

```js
// client.ts

declare namespace App {
    interface Session {
        token?: string
    }
}

export default new HoudiniClient({
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',

    fetchParams({ session }) {
        const {token } = session as App.Session
        return {
            headers: {
                cookie: `token=${token}`
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In my route, I have a `+page.gql` file fetching the data, and this works well when the server is asked to fetch the data; however, when the client is used to fetch the data (when navigating to a link for example), the `HoudiniClient` isn't used (reasonably), but the request goes out without the cookies, even though it goes out to the same URL and path - what I would expect the browser to do.

This is even when the cookies are set to be `SameSite=Lax`, `HttpOnly=false`, and `Secure=false`.

I've tried using `_houdini_beforeLoad` but it has no access to the client's cookies, and the same with Svelte's `load`.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?